# How to append multiple XML files

Tags: php, xml

I have a large XML file which takes forever to load on external FTP editor so I would like to split it into several files.

I use `simplexml_load_file` but couldn't make it load multiple files into same array.

XML files has the same structure, here's a sample of each file:

**a.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?> 
<queries>
    <query>
      <admin_user_type>user</admin_user_type>
      <show_in_menu>True</show_in_menu>
      <title>Dashboard</title>
      <vertical_report>True</vertical_report>
  </query>
</queries>
```

**b.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<queries>
    <query>
        <admin_user_type>admin</admin_user_type>
        <show_in_menu>false</show_in_menu>
        <title>Profile Element</title>
        <input_name>Id</input_name>
        <input_type>hidden</input_type>
    </query>
</queries>
```

There are about 200 queries in 7,000 lines between the two files.

The code fails on the foreach below:

```
$xml = read_xml_files();
foreach($xml->children() as $xml) {
    ...
    ...
}
```

Below is what I've taken from Nigel's suggestion:

```
function read_xml_files() {
    $target = new DOMDocument();
    $target->loadXML('<base />');
    mergeFile($target, XML_FILES_FOLDER."a.xml");
    mergeFile($target, XML_FILES_FOLDER."b.xml");
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($target);
    return $xml->asXML();
}

function mergeFile ( DOMDocument $target, $fileName )    {
$source = new DOMDocument();
$source->load($fileName);

foreach ( $source->childNodes as $row )   {
    $import = $target->importNode($row, true);
    $target->documentElement->appendChild($import);
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestion!

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so we can understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: So do you want the code to split the file or to put the data back together?

Comment: Lawrence Cherone: I am using $files = array_slice(scandir($myfolder), 2) to read the files into an array and tried using array_merge but it didn't work.

Comment: Nigel Ren: Yes, I would like to put the data back together.

Comment: Note that is the problem is to read large files that it may be a good idea to look for a SAX parser or a pull based XML parser (XMLReader). DOM based parsers try and load the entire document into memory at once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use DOMDocument to do the main merging part...

```
function mergeFile ( DOMDocument $target, $fileName )    {
    $source = new DOMDocument();
    $source->load($fileName);

    foreach ( $source->childNodes as $row )   {
        $import = $target->importNode($row, true);
        $target->documentElement->appendChild($import);
    }
}
$target = new DOMDocument();
$target->loadXML('<base />');
mergeFile($target, "file1.xml");
mergeFile($target, "file2.xml");

$xml = simplexml_import_dom($target);
echo $xml->asXML();
```

At the end $xml contains the merged files.

Note that this adds another level to the document (unless I know the type of contents it's difficult to do anything else).  So in this case you will get something like...

file1.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<A>A</A>
```

file2.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<B>B</B>
```

Result will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<base>
<A>A</A>
<B>B</B>
</base>
```

**Update:**

You could also try...

```
function read_xml_files() {
    $target = new DOMDocument();
    $target->loadXML('<queries />');
    mergeFile($target, "NewFile.xml");
    mergeFile($target, "NewFile1.xml");
    $xml = simplexml_import_dom($target);
    return $xml->asXML();
}

function mergeFile ( DOMDocument $target, $fileName )    {
    $source = new DOMDocument();
    $source->load($fileName);

    foreach ( $source->getElementsByTagName("query") as $row )   {
        $import = $target->importNode($row, true);
        $target->documentElement->appendChild($import);
    }
}
```

This merges the file so that the result is

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<queries>
    <query>
        <admin_user_type>user</admin_user_type>
        <show_in_menu>True</show_in_menu>
        <title>Dashboard</title>
        <vertical_report>True</vertical_report>
    </query>
    <query>
        <admin_user_type>admin</admin_user_type>
        <show_in_menu>false</show_in_menu>
        <title>Profile Element</title>
        <input_name>Id</input_name>
        <input_type>hidden</input_type>
    </query>
</queries>
```

Comment: I've been playing with this for few hours now and couldn't overcome the following error: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function children() on string which is shown when I try to use the content of $xml->asXML()

Comment: Do you have some sample data and a copy of your code.

Comment: The read_xml_files function was returning the source of the XML (`return $xml->asXML();`) -so this is a string, as you want the SimpleXMLElement itself, change that to ` return $xml;`

Comment: I've added a new code example which merges the files slightly differently, it may be better if it suites your needs. (although correct the file names as I've my own test files.)

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot Nigel.